# Javascript. Submit form after user stop typing

Tags: javascript

How i can submit form after user complete typing input? 
Example: The user started typing. After the introduction of several characters stopped. The form was submited.

Comment: This is possible but it's terrible design. Unless the input is supposed to be really short, this could really annoy your users.

Comment: I need to make a search form that will make a request to the server after each pause between input.This is the customer's desire

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a example for you.

```
var timer;              
var doneTypingInterval = 3000; // wait 3 seconds
var $input = $('input');

$input.on('keyup', function () {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
});

$input.on('keydown', function () {
  clearTimeout(timer);
});

function doneTyping () {
  alert('done')
}
```

Html

```
<input type="text">
```

But i don't recommend this. It can be annoying for your user's.

Comment: Sorry i am new there. I think if i paste jsfiddle link it will automatically paste codes.

Comment: Reversed my vote. It's fine to post fiddle links, but the code should also be posted in the answer. You can also just post a stack snippet instead of a fiddle link.

Answer (score 0):

i hope this sample helps :

HTML

```
<form>
<input name="query" id="query">
<p id="message" > </p>
</form>
```

JS

```
function submitForm(){
    //do some stuff
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    window.timeout=null;
    jQuery('#query').on('keyup', function(event){
        clearTimeout(window.timeout);
        window.timeout = setTimeout(submitForm, 1000); // waits 1 second for user to press a new key 
    });
});
```